# Limit grep to first match per line

Tags: regex, linux, shell, command-line, grep

I'm trying to grep for all lines that have the letter `a` before the first period in the line.

Here's an example file:

```
test123a.hello
example.more-test-a.xyz
stacka.tester.this
nothing.nothing.nothing
```

In the example above, I'd want to `grep` these 2 lines:

```
test123a.hello
stacka.tester.this
```

This is what I've tried:

```
grep ".*a\." test.txt
```

That is getting the 2 lines I want, but it's also getting this line, which I don't want, be the `a` is in front of the second period, not the first one:

```
example.more-test-a.xyz
```

How do I limit it to just get the lines with `a` before the first period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ grep '^[^.]*a\.' test.txt
test123a.hello
stacka.tester.this
```

- `^` to restrict matching at start of line
- `[^.]*` to match any character other than `.` character, zero or more times
- `a` literally match character `a`
- `\.` literally match character `.`

You can also use `awk` here, which is more suited for field based processing

```
$ # 'a' as last character for first field
$ awk -F'.' '$1 ~ /a$/' test.txt
test123a.hello
stacka.tester.this

$ # 'a' as last character for second field
$ awk -F'.' '$2 ~ /a$/' test.txt
example.more-test-a.xyz
```

Comment: Or same regex in `awk`: `awk '/^[^.]*a\./' file`

Answer (score 0):

if you feel many output, you can try

> grep ".*a." test.txt | less

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying, but that the same command I'm already using, you've just added `| less` behind it and you're not escaping the period...

Answer (score 0):

You can try [EDITED]

```
grep ".*a." test.txt | grep -v "\([^a]\.\)\{1,\}.*a."
```

This will do your first grep and denies anything with "a." preceded by a dot.

Comment: That almost does it, but it doesn't detect lines like this:  `testa.helloa.example` because the second period has an `a` before it.

Comment: I edited the answer, putting a conditional, indicating to deny anything with one or more occurrences of dot without a succeeded by "a."